# CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cors

I created an application in AngularJS and I'm trying to make calls to the Laravel API:

- MyApp (AngularJS): **http://localhost:8080/**
- API (Laravel Boilerplate): **http://localhost:8000/**

I use Laravel [API Boilerplate (JWT Edition)](https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt) to API.

But I get this error in the browser console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried to apply the cors middleware (barryvdh/laravel-cors) in api_routes.php but the error remains.

api_routes.php:

```
<?php

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['middleware' => 'cors'], function ($api) {

    $api->post('auth/login', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@login');
    $api->post('auth/signup', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@signup');
    $api->post('auth/recovery', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@recovery');
    $api->post('auth/reset', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@reset');

    // example of protected route
    $api->get('protected', ['middleware' => ['api.auth'], function () {     
        return \App\User::all();
    }]);

    // example of free route
    $api->get('free', function() {
        return \App\User::all();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand this, but when i want cross browser access i add a .htaccess file into the folder where my endpoint is with the following in it:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm completely wrong about this implementation. The `origin` header has a specific placement case in Laravel, where other headers can be defined in Middleware, the `origin` header **cannot**.

Instead, you need to add this to the top of your main `routes.php` file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080');
```

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy I tried this, and try again after you answer and the error continues. I have no idea what is in my AngularJS application I do not need to change anything ok?

Comment: @MateusVitali See my update, I just did some testing and what I found is that the `Origin` header must be set in your `routes.php` file (or earlier) in order to be applied correctly. Other headers can be set on the response in Middleware. I'm not 100% sure why yet, but this is what I've found. Give that a shot.

Comment: better quality of printscreen: https://s31.postimg.org/synyo4vrf/error.png
https://s31.postimg.org/4w74t9f4b/error2.jpg

Comment: @MateusVitali I can see that the header is being supplied to you in the response, so it's working! Can you check and see what's going on with that PHP error and get it disabled? It's stopping the headers from being modified by the server because of thew rite.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly CORS issues are server related, if it is not getting solved by .htaccess, same headers u can give from application starter file. so have understanding of domain name, where is pointed to folder path of application. In Laravel index.php is starter file so use the following lines of code and add in starting lines.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

cache clear in browser needed for loading web-app

Answer (score 0):

you should add an nginx virtual host pointing to your api with a proxy pass. essentially you need to make sure both your front and backend are fed from the same domain

Comment: But I wish I could put in different domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Cors middleware class and add into the application's global HTTP middleware stack in kenel.php. Middlewares in this stack will run during every request to your application.

Try [this](https://codingguider.com/742/how-to-avoid-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-error/).

Answer (score -1):

Add this on top of `routes.php` file or `api.php` file depending on where you have placed your routes:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Adding these 3 lines in the site where you are making the request to, solves the CORS problem. The above will allow JS running on http://localhost:8080 to make request to the backend which contains the above lines.

The answer is inspired from @Dallas Caley's answer.